# Entries loop that doesn’t take the status into account?

Tags: matrix, elementcriteriamodel

How do I create an entries loop that will pull content even if the entry in the loop is not set to Live?

e.g., I have a Matrix so a user can select entries to feature in a slider. They want the slider to feature entries even if the entry itself is currently hidden/unpublished.

```
{% for caseStudy in entry.featuredCaseStudies %}
    <div class="slide">
        <div class="text">
            {% if caseStudy.status == 'live' %}<a href="{{ caseStudy.url }}">{% endif %}
                <img src="{{ caseStudy.caseStudy.first().clientLogo.first().getUrl('caseStudyTumbnail') }}" alt="" />
            {% if caseStudy.status == 'live' %}</a>{% endif %}
        </div><!-- .text -->
    </div><!-- .slide -->
{% endfor %}
```

This works only in as much as the anchor is only output if the linked entry is live. But I can't get it to spit out the image; presumably because the entry isn't live.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer**

Change this line:

```
{% for caseStudy in entry.featuredCaseStudies %}
```

to:

```
{% for caseStudy in entry.featuredCaseStudies.status(null) %}
```

**Long answer**

If “featuredCaseStudies” is an Entries field, then typing `entry.featuredCaseStudies` will give you an [ElementCriteriaModel](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/elementcriteriamodel) object, configured to return all of the entries related to `entry` via that “featuredCaseStudies” field (using the [relatedTo](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/craft.entries#relatedTo) param). Just like the ElementCriteriaModel object you get when typing `craft.entries`, you’re free to chain in additional parameters after `entry.featuredCaseStudies`.

By default, entry-targetting ElementCriteriaModel objects will only return “live” entries – entries that are enabled, and whose Post Date is in the past, and whose Expiry Date is either not set or set in the future. You can alter that behavior using entries’ [status](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/craft.entries#status) criteria param. Setting it to `null` tells Craft to not factor entries’ statuses into the query whatsoever, which is what you’re looking for here.

Comment: Ah, I see! My problem was I was trying to go through a Matrix to do this (featuredCaseStudies was a Matrix, which had a block type that was Entries). This didn't work for that arragement, but I realised I could switch it to a plain Entries field rather than having to have a Matrix in this case. Thanks!

Comment: Ah gotcha - and now `caseStudy.caseStudy.first()` makes more sense; `caseStudy.caseStudy` was the Entries field; not `entry.featuredCaseStudies`. Was there any reason you did this with a Matrix field and sub-Entries field, rather than just a simple Entries field? (It looks like you had `status` and `url` fields on your Matrix blocks as well? Were those actually necessary or would it have been better to grab the actual case study entries’ statuses and URLs rather than duplicating that data in your Matrix field?)

Comment: Reason I ask is because you can get it to work either way - you just would need to add that `.status(null)` param to the _actual_ Entries field reference (`caseStudy.caseStudy.status(null)` rather than to `entry.featuredCaseStudies`.

Comment: In this case no, I'd just got stuck in a Matrix mindset, but I can see it being useful in a Matrix in future projects. Thanks for the info :)